# How to save a kivy canvas object as an image file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I was wondering if it is possible to save a canvas that had several textures painted on it as an image file.

I know I can save regular Image's (kivy.core.image) or Texture's (kivy.graphics.texture) as an image file with the save() function, so if I am able to convert the canvas to an Image or a Texture it should be easy, but so far I wasn't able to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Widgets have an `export_to_png` method. Call this from the Widget whose canvas you have drawn on.

Comment: Such a simple thing, yet I could not find it anywhere. Thank you very much

Comment: See also: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.image.html#kivy.core.image.Image.save

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `MyPainter` widget has its default size of `(100,100)` and its default position `(0,0)`. So it is actually behind your `Save` `Button`. So all your drawing is actually outside the `MyPainter` widget, and saving the widget to an image is blank.

The fix is to change the `pos` and `size` of `MyPainter`, and perhaps use `collide_point()` in your `on_touch_down()` and `on_touch_move()` methods to ensure that you are actually drawing on the `MyPainter` widget.